# Mostrar mensagem quando filtro não encontrar resultado

Tags: jquery

Estou usando [o excelente plugin Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) para filtrar itens de uma página.

A filtragem ocorre de acordo com as classes utilizadas nas `li` que são referenciadas nos `option`. Ao selecionar um filtro, os elementos corretamente referenciados são exibidos, e os que não combinam ficam ocultos.

Porém quando o filtro não encontrar nenhum resultado, seria necessário exibir uma mensagem no lugar dizendo "Nenhum resultado encontrado", ao invés do espaço vazio.

Observem o [JSFiddle com o código](http://jsfiddle.net/ecpkryae/). Selecione no filtro "Cidade 4" ou "Escola 4", onde a coluna do meio não mostrará resultados.

**Exemplo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha primeira sugestão é criar um item para "sem resultados" e colocá-lo junto aos outros. Dê-lhe uma classe especial de modo que ele não fique visível junto com os outros (quanto não houver filtro algum, por exemplo):

```
<li class="sem-resultados">
    Nenhum resultado encontrado
</li>
```

A princípio, só isso seria suficiente para ele ficar escondido (pois ele não possui a classe `produkt-element`, mas no seu código antes de se fazer qualquer filtragem ele ainda permanece visível. Coloque então uma regra no seu CSS para escondê-lo de fato:

```
.sem-resultados {
    display: none;
}
```

Com um item desse em cada coluna, vamos à filtragem: sempre que o plugin termina de dispor os elementos na tela, ocorre o evento `layoutComplete`. Nesse evento, você pode contar quantos elementos *em cada coluna* estão visíveis, e se não houver nenhum, mostrar o `.sem-resultados`:

```
$(".isotope.full").each(function() {
    var semResultados = $(this).find(".sem-resultados");
    var algumVisivel = $(this).find("li:visible").length > 0;
    semResultados.toggle(!algumVisivel);
});
```

Entretanto, encontrei dois problemas com essa abordagem:

1. Quando o `layoutComplete` é chamado, os elementos ainda têm a mesma visibilidade que tinham antes (pois me parece que esse evento ocorre **antes** da transição suave dos elementos, não ao seu final). Isso torna um pouco mas complicado saber se há algum elemento visível ou não.

   Um *workaround* é usar um `setTimeout` para executar o código acima só depois que todos os eventos pendentes já tiverem sido executados:

   ```
   $container.isotope("on", "layoutComplete", function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
           $(".isotope.full").each(function() {
               var semResultados = $(this).find(".sem-resultados");
               var algumVisivel = $(this).find("li:visible").length > 0;
               semResultados.toggle(!algumVisivel);
           });
       }, 500);
   });
   ```
2. Pelo mesmo motivo, se na filtragem anterior o elemento "sem resultados" estava visível, na nova ele é mostrado "por cima" dos elementos presentes até que o *workaround* acima seja executado, causando um efeito visual desagradável... A solução é esconder o `.sem-resultados` logo antes da filtragem:

   ```
    $(".sem-resultados").hide();
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
   ```

[Exemplo final](http://jsfiddle.net/ecpkryae/4/). O efeito visual pode <del>não ser o melhor possível</del> ser um bocado desagradável, mas foi o que eu consegui dadas as restrições impostas por esse plugin.

---

**Atualização:** Se você não se importar de perder a transição suave, basta atribuir para zero a propriedade `transitionDuration`:

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.produkt-element',
    transitionDuration: "0"
});
```

E assim você pode colocar o *timeout* também em `0` (mas é preciso mantê-lo de qualquer forma). Assim [não tem atraso, só um ligeiro *"flicker"*...](http://jsfiddle.net/ecpkryae/7/) :)

Comment: Dessa forma só a coluna "Pós-Graduação" aparece a mensagem?

Comment: @Laerte A princípio não, qualquer uma das 3 colunas deveria mostrar. Algo não está funcionando? Se sim, por favor me dê um exemplo de filtro no qual a 1ª ou 3ª coluna fica vazia, pra eu testar.

Comment: Filtro: Cidade: 5 e Escola 2.

Comment: Editei o código e acrescentei um filtro que não dá nenhum resultado.
http://jsfiddle.net/ecpkryae/3/.

Comment: @Laerte Aff, pelo jeito um `timeout` baixo por alguma razão não está dando conta do recado... Mudando o `timeout` pra `500` ele parece funcionar em todos os casos, mas o atraso é visualmente desagradável... Quanto a isso, estou sem ideia do que fazer pra melhorar :(

Comment: `+1` também andei a testar o plugin e não cheguei a melhores resultados

Comment: @Sergio Tentei também uma solução com CSS puro mas não tive sucesso. Por acaso você sabe por que `li ~ .sem-resultados` [funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/ecpkryae/5/) mas `li:visible ~ .sem-resultados` [não funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/ecpkryae/6/)?! (independentemente do plugin, filtragem, etc, o fato é que o seletor parece não estar fazendo nada - muito embora o elemento **tenha** irmãos visíveis...)

Comment: @mgibsonbr esse pseudo é nativo? [Não o encontro na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

Comment: @Sergio Está explicado então, ele deve ser [só do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)... :( Parecia tão promissor, e não encontro outro meio de selecionar por visibilidade. Valeu!

Comment: @mgibsonbr obrigado pela resposta e toda pesquisa em cima da minha pergunta.
Mesmo com o efeito que você não gostou, o resultado é exatamente o que eu preciso. Qualquer coisa troco pra versão sem efeitos de transição.
Agradeço também sua didática em responder e explicar tudo certinho.
Marquei sua resposta como correta.
Obrigado :)